# Editing python script

Tags: python

I want for each collection day from the date of "LastStationsFetch" until today, a separate file is created in each station's directory to store the data for that specific day. But for the moment the script collects the data, creates the directory but saves everything in a single file. but I want one file per station.

```
import zeep
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json
import sys
import datetime
import os


def WebServiceErrorControl(ErrorNumber):
    if ErrorNumber == -1:
        print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | Login error")
        flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | Logoin web/s error\n")
    elif ErrorNumber == -2:
        print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | unknown argument")
        flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR |  unknown argument\n")
    elif ErrorNumber == -4:
        print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | Station not found")
        flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | Station not found\n")
    elif ErrorNumber == -5:
        print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : INFO | No data available")
        flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : INFO | No data available\n")
    elif ErrorNumber == -15:
        print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | No data available")
        flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | No data available\n")
    else:
        print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | unknown error\n")
        flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | unknown error\n")


# Open log file for troubleshooting
with open("log_"+datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.log', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as flog:
    # Manage Exception
    try:
        flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")+" : INFO | Script start"+"\n")
        
        # Read context
        with open('config.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
            data = myfile.read()
        
        # parse json file
        obj = json.loads(data)
        
        # Load static parameter
        login = str(obj['login'])
        password = str(obj['password'])
        identifier = str(obj['id'])
        default_value = str(obj['default_value'])
        
        NowDate = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        NowDate_str = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
        obj['last_run'] = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M:%S")
        
        # Connexion to the webservice
        wsdl = obj['url']
        print("WebService connexion on : " + wsdl)
        flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : INFO |WebService connexion on : " + wsdl +"\n")
        client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
        
        print("WebService connexion in progress")
        connection = client.service.OpenConnection(login, password, identifier)
        
        if connection.body.OpenConnectionResult in [True, "1"]:
            print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : WebService connexion successful")
            flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : INFO | WebService connexion successful" + "\n")
        else:
            print("Connexion failure | Status : " + str(connection.body.OpenConnectionResult))
            flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | end of script due to connexion failure | Status : " + str(connection.body.OpenConnectionResult) + "\n")
            # Log End of script
            quit()
        
        print("\nGetVersion()")
        Version = client.service.GetVersion()
        Version = str(Version.body.GetVersionResult)
        print(Version)
        if Version.find("Error:") == -1:
            flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : INFO | WebService : " + Version + "\n")
        else:
            print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | GetWebService Version Error \n")
            flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | GetWebService Version Error \n")
        
        # run all jobs
        for job in obj['job']:
            print("\n--- Job N°" + str(obj['job'].index(job) + 1) + " ---")
            param = ",".join(job['param'])
            stations = job['stations']
            LastStationsFetch = job['LastStationsFetch']
            granularity = job['granularity']
            date_format = job['date_format']
            filename = job['filename']
            path = job['path']
            filetype = job['filetype']
            header = str(job['header'])
            stations_label = job['stations_label']
            
            # Create folder for each station if it does not exist
            for station in stations:
                station_folder_path = os.path.join(path, station)
                if not os.path.exists(station_folder_path):
                    os.makedirs(station_folder_path)
            
            # To initialize LastStationFetch
            while len(LastStationsFetch) < len(stations):
                job['LastStationsFetch'].append("")
            
            while len(stations_label) < len(stations):
                job['stations_label'].append("")
            ErrorNo = 0  # Initialisation de la variable ErrorNo
          
            for idx, station in enumerate(stations):
                print("\n--- Job N°" + str(obj['job'].index(job) + 1) + " ---")
                param = ",".join(job['param'])
                stations = job['stations']
                LastStationsFetch = job['LastStationsFetch']
                granularity = job['granularity']
                date_format = job['date_format']
                time_format = job['time_format']
                filename = job['filename']
                path = job['path']
                filetype = job['filetype']
                header = str(job['header'])
                stations_label = job['stations_label']
                
                # Create folder for each station if it does not exist
                for station in stations:
                    station_folder_path = os.path.join(path, station)
                    if not os.path.exists(station_folder_path):
                        os.makedirs(station_folder_path)
                
                # To initialize LastStationFetch
                while len(LastStationsFetch) < len(stations):
                    job['LastStationsFetch'].append("")
                
                while len(stations_label) < len(stations):
                    job['stations_label'].append("")
                ErrorNo = 0  # Initialisation de la variable ErrorNo
                for idx, station in enumerate(stations):
                    print("Job N°" + str(obj['job'].index(job) + 1) + "|Export : " + station)
                    flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : INFO | " + station + "| Export station\n")
                    LastStationFetch = LastStationsFetch[idx]
                    try:
                        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(LastStationFetch, '%Y%m%d%H%M')
                    except ValueError:
                        # Get the first data recorded
                        try:
                            FirstRecordedDate = client.service.GetFirstRecordedDate(station, granularity)
                            FirstRecordedDate = str(FirstRecordedDate.body.GetFirstRecordedDateResult)
                            col = FirstRecordedDate.find("Error:")
                            if col == -1:
                                date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(FirstRecordedDate, '%Y%m%d%H%M')
                            else:
                                ErrorNo = int((FirstRecordedDate[(col + len("Error:")):]))
                                WebServiceErrorControl(ErrorNo)
                                continue
                        except ValueError:
                            print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | Unknown error about first data recorded")
                            flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | Unknown error about first data recorded\n")
                            continue
                    
                    LastStationFetch = date_time_obj
                    if granularity == "U":
                        get_data_limit = 7  # 7 days
                    elif granularity == "X":
                        get_data_limit = 31  # 31 days
                    elif granularity == "H":
                        get_data_limit = 180  # 180 days
                    elif granularity == "J":
                        get_data_limit = 365  # 365 days
                    
                    StartCursorDate = date_time_obj
                    StopCursorDate = NowDate
                    
                    # Limit the size of the Web Service request
                    if (StopCursorDate - StartCursorDate).days > get_data_limit:
                        StopCursorDate = date_time_obj + datetime.timedelta(days=get_data_limit)
                    
                    # Add the code to create files for each day
                    while StopCursorDate <= NowDate:
                        if StopCursorDate != NowDate:
                            StopCursorDate = StartCursorDate + datetime.timedelta(days=get_data_limit)
                        else:
                            if granularity == "J" or granularity == "D":
                                StartCursorDate += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                            elif granularity == "H":
                                StartCursorDate += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
                            elif granularity == "X":
                                StartCursorDate += datetime.timedelta(minutes=6)
                            else:
                                StartCursorDate += datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
                        
                                 
               # Request to the Web Service
                        Value = client.service.GetBlockSortedValue(station, param, granularity, StartCursorDate.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M"), StopCursorDate.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M"), "ASC")
                        Value = Value.body.GetBlockSortedValueResult
                        # Control API Web Service result
                        if Value.find("Error:") == -1:
                            root = ET.fromstring(Value)
                            NewestDate = root[len(root) - 1].text.partition(',')[0]
                            job['LastStationsFetch'][idx] = NewestDate
                            
                            # Open/create file to store the data for the current day
                            current_day_filename = filename + "_" + station + "_" + StartCursorDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + '.' + filetype
                            current_day_filepath = os.path.join(path, station, current_day_filename)
                            with open(current_day_filepath, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                                if header == "True":
                                    f.write(param + "\n")
                                    header = "False"
                                
                                for data in root.findall('LINEDATA'):
                                    ParamValue = (data.text).split(",")
                                    k = [i.replace(' ', '') for i in ParamValue]
                                    ParamValue = k
                                    
                                    # Timestamp format
                                    timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(ParamValue[0], '%Y%m%d%H%M')
                                    line = timestamp.strftime(date_format) + "," + timestamp.strftime(time_format) + ","
                                    #line = timestamp.strftime(date_format) + ","
                                    
                                    # Process the data received
                                    for i in range(param.count(',') + 1):
                                        if ParamValue[i + 1] == "":
                                            ParamValue[i + 1] = default_value
                                        
                                        line += ParamValue[i + 1] + ","
                                    
                                    f.write(line.rstrip(',') + "\n")
                        elif Value.find("-5") != -1:
                            print("No data between " + StartCursorDate.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M") + " and " + StopCursorDate.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M") + "\n")
                            print("Next Block will be requested")
                        # Case of API Web Service result error
                        elif Value.find("-2") != -1:
                            print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | unknown argument")
                            flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR |  unknown argument\n")
                            break
                        else:
                            col = Value.find("Error:")
                            ErrorNo = int((Value[(col + len("Error:")):]))
                            WebServiceErrorControl(ErrorNo)
                            break
                        
                        # Next API Web Service iteration
                        StartCursorDate = StopCursorDate
                        if StopCursorDate == NowDate:
                            break
                    
                    try:
                        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(LastStationsFetch[idx], '%Y%m%d%H%M')
                    except ValueError:
                        break
                    
                    if ErrorNo == 0:
                        flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : INFO | " + station + "| No new data for station | Last data received at " + date_time_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "\n")
                    else:
                        continue                                  
        # Save JSON context for next run
        with open('config.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(obj, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
            flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : INFO | Context saved\n")
        
        # Log End of script
        print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : INFO | Gracefully end of script\n")
        flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : INFO | Gracefully end of script\n")
    
    # Manage general exception
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception : " + str(e))
        flog.write(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " : ERROR | " + str(e) + "\n")

# Log End of script
quit()
#pp
```

I want for each collection day from the date of "LastStationsFetch" until today, a separate file is created in each station's directory to store the data for that specific day. But for the moment the script collects the data, creates the directory but saves everything in a single file. but I want one file per station.